# LG 29um59-p monitor stuck in low resolution - Ubuntu 17.10.1

Tags: display-resolution

I am new to Ubuntu and wanted to try it in my new desktop PC setup, but when I installed it the resolution is stuck at only 1024x768 (4:3).

I have:

- LG 29um59-p monitor (21:9), that supports 2560x1080
- Intel I3-8100, MSI Z370-A Pro with built in graphics.

I tried to run it on Windows 7 and it works in 2560x1080.

I read that there have been some issues similar to mine, but I was not able to solve it on my own as this is my first time using Ubuntu.

Can someone suggest a solution?

Comment: It might be helpful if you could [edit] into your question where you read about these similar issues.